# 'int' not iterable error in python While running pyldavis

Tags: python-2.7, visualization, lda

- I am running my code in ipython(running python version 2.7). 
  Found error while calling "pyLDAvis" funtion to visualize my LDA generated topics. 
  Following error :

topics_df = pd.DataFrame([dict((y,x) for x, y in tuples) for tuples in topics])TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

- Input data is in the form of a table which has two columns "complaints_ID" and "complaints_txt". I am trying to run topic model on each of the complaint_txt value

Is this issue with Python version or arguments I am passing to this function?
Below is my code.

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk import bigrams
from lib.lda import lda, visualizeLDA
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim
import pyLDAvis.gensim

#provide path name here
mypath = " "
allcomplaints = pd.read_csv(mypath)
#combining complaints for each ID
myremarks= allcomplaints.groupby(['complaint_ID'])['complaint_txt'].agg(lambda x: ''.join(x)).values 
#create English stop words list
en_stop = get_stop_words('en')

#including domain specific stop words
my_stopwords = ["xx","xxxx"]
my_stopwords= [i.decode('utf-8') for i in my_stopwords]
en_stop = en_stop +my_stopwords

texts = []
for doc in myremarks:
        raw = doc.lower()
        tokens = bigrams(i for i in tokenizer.tokenize(raw)if not i in en_stop and len(i)>1)
        mergedtokens = [i[0]+" "+i[1] for i in tokens]
        stopped_tokens = [i for i in mergedtokens if not i in en_stop]
        texts.append(stopped_tokens)
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
print dictionary
    # convert tokenized documents into a document-term matrix
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

    # generate LDA model
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics = 5 , id2word = dictionary, passes = 1)
print(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=5))

#     Visualize ldamodel
vis= pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(ldamodel,corpus,dictionary)
pyLDAvis.display(vis)
```

# Following is the sample of data I am using to run LDA:

```
Complaint_ID| Complaint_txt
------------| --------------
4545        | cust has billing issue
4545        | for $480 
6878        | connct issue for a day ne
6878        | ed immediate resoltn
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @AllDani.com. I just updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: 'print' every thing that you want to iterate over (do a 'for loop') on. Are all of them indeed lists? Is one of them maybe a number?

Comment: @AllDani.com. Please check the updated question which has sample data I am trying to run. Thanks!

Comment: What is the wanted result from the shown chart?

Comment: @AllDani.com. I am looking for topics from each complaint. Ex: Billing

Comment: Your sample data shows no column named billing.

Comment: @AllDani.com.. The complaint_txt value in the first 2 records is a billing issue. I want to identify such topics from each complaint.

Comment: You want a loop that creates a list of the lines under txt?

Comment: @AllDani.com.. I have an error while creating visualization "Pyldavis". I guess there is some issue related to that.

Comment: Add error to question

Comment: @alldani. Hi . It is the first bullet point in my question. Thanks!

Comment: My bad. People usualy put errors at end of question.